# CSS for default scrollbar of Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I need to customize only the width of the scrollbars of Chrome browser using CSS, but need rest of things (like hover effect, color on hover, scrollbar track color, scrollbar button color etc, color of scrollbar on click etc.) as it is.

How can I do it?
I know that we can change the width of the scrollbar using following css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/ is a good article about it, with a couple nice examples

Comment: @elveti - what is the file name where I have to put this css ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

Comment: From where did you find it? Can developer tool tell me this?

Answer (score -1):

You can do like that

`::-webkit-scrollbar` is for the entire scrollbar

`handle` is scrollbar where you can add background like that and apply also `pseudo elements` or the draggable scrolling handle.

`track` is the `progress bar` of the scrollbar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #1B242F; 
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #04C2C9; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background: #04C2; 
}
```

For more info visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) link

Comment: but where should I put this `css` ?

Comment: you can put it in any of your css file

Comment: where can i see which css file I have? Give me a name.

Comment: you need to copy that code and paste it in the `.css` file of your code.

Comment: Oh god! I want ot change the scrollbar in my browser, by editing local css file, so that my browser always has this color scrollbar, regardless which website I visit. Same as I would by editing `UserContent.css` in my local profile for `firefox`.

Comment: this question solve the problem of `chrome` not firefox, do a google first, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar